# RequestContext throws NPE from a different context than FacesContext

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Why calling `RequestContext rq = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()` from a different context than `FacesContext` throws a `NullPointerException` ?

I am not able to do something like :

```
RequestContext rq = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance() //NPE is thrown
if (rq != null) {
..
}
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve a bean inside a `WebFilter` and call a method. This method uses above snippet; so it throws `NullPointerException`.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance of `RequestContext` is saved as an attribute in `FacesContext`, so when there is not `FacesContext` you will have NPE. Here is the code which will tell you how `RequestContext` is obtained, and that will be cleared:

```
return (RequestContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes().get(Constants.REQUEST_CONTEXT_ATTR);
```

Creating `RequestContext` and saving it as `FacesContext` attribute is done in `PhaseListener` of Primefaces, after ***Restore view phase***, so it doesn't exist in your filter.